# Connection could not be established with host : stream_socket_client(): (Connection refused)

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-8

mi proyecto de laravel esta alojado en un host del cual obtengo mi direccion de correo pero al mandar un email laravel me regresa el siguiente error
"Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.mboxhosting.com:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.mboxhosting.com:465 (Connection refused)"

mis datos en el .Env son los sigueintes:
(Que a mi entender son correctos)

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mboxhosting.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME="********"
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="devs@learnbox.work"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="LearnBox"
```